# Why isn't my read statement recording binary data

Tags: c++, io

I have a large document that has two pieces.  The first is a header, which uses standard characters and ends with `[END]`.  The second part is in binary, and looks something like: **`NUL DLE NUL DC1 NUL`**.  I am attempting to read in this document using an ifstream.  My code is:

```
std::string filename = "file.txt";
std::ifstream originalFile;
originalFile.open(filename,std::ios::binary);

std::streampos fsize = 0;
fsize = originalFile.tellg();
originalFile.open(0,std::ios::end);
fsize = originalFile.tellg() - fsize;

char * buffer = new char [int(fsize)];
originalFile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
originalFile.reade(buffer,fsize);

std::cout << fsize << std::endl;
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

When I run it, The program outputs the entire header of my file, and then ends.  It does not access or print any of the binary data.  Is this the right command to be using? If not, is there something else I can try?

Comment: doesn't the `originalFile.open(0,std::ios::end);` should be replaced by a `seekg()`? use `gcount()` after `read()` to check if you've read fsize bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dump of the file data (which presumably;y really looks like `std::cout <<  buffer << std::endl;`) is stopping when it hits the `NUL` character which it considers to be the end of a C-style string.

Comment: Oh, I see.  So the data is being saved just not printed? Is there a way to tell my print to go ahead and print everything?

Comment: A couple options: convert the buffer to a `std::string` using something like `string(buffer,fsize)` and output that string object; write a loop that outputs the data in the buffer character by character.  Note that if you're outputting to the console (the default for `cout` unless you've done redirection) you're likely to get some rather difficult to read output. Depending on your needs you might want the program to convert such binary data to hex or the ASCII names (like `DLE` or `DC1`).